# Gatling: upload simulation.log to S3 bucket from simulation

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, gatling, scala-gatling

I would like to upload the `simulation.log` file of a scenario to an S3 bucket once my simulation is finished.

I was thinking of adding the upload in the `after` block of my simulation.

I didn't find any example that does that. I only found scripts external to the simulation taking care if it.

Is there any reason why I shouldn't do it?

If not, how can I get the absolute path of the `simulation.log`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately block 'after' execute early then generating report.
I would advise writing a script that runs after the test.

1. Go to directory with the last report.

```
cd target/gatling && cd "$(ls -td -- */ | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f1)"
```

2. Use aws cli for upload to s3

```
aws s3 cp simulation.log s3://my-bucket/
```